# how to use fopen, fgets, flose properly? It works fine but later sometime the count just goes down to random number

Tags: php

> It works fine but later sometime the count just goes down to random
>   number. My guess is my code cannot process multiple visits at a time.
>   [Where increment heppens](http://insideshowbiz.onemega.com/exclusive-kisses-delavin-inaming-love-team-na-sila-ni-donny-pangilinan/)
>   [Where it displays the count](http://insideshowbiz.onemega.com/loveteams/)

```
<?php
$args_loveteam = array('child_of' => 474);
$loveteam_children = get_categories($args_loveteam);
if(in_category('loveteams', $post->ID)){
    foreach ($loveteam_children as $loveteam_child) {
        $post_slug = $loveteam_child->slug;
        echo "<script>console.log('".$post_slug."');</script>";
        if(in_category($loveteam_child->name)){
                    /* counter */
              // opens file to read saved hit number
                    if($loveteam_child->slug == "loveteam-mayward"){
                        $datei = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-".$post_slug."-2.txt","r");
                    }else{
                        $datei = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-".$post_slug.".txt","r");
                    }
            $count = fgets($datei,1000);
            fclose($datei);
            $count=$count + 1 ;

            // opens file to change new hit number
                    if($loveteam_child->slug == "loveteam-mayward"){
                        $datei = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-".$post_slug."-2.txt","w");
                    }else{
                        $datei = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-".$post_slug.".txt","w");
                    }
            fwrite($datei, $count);
            fclose($datei);
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Probably have Race conditions, file storage is not [A.C.I.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) complaint.  In other words there is no guarantee files can handle concurrent writes in an atomic and isolated fashion.  We won't even get into the issues of crashes or write failures leaving it in an unstable state.... etc.etc.  In otherwords I wouldn't rely on file system for anything that happens concurrently unless you have a really good way to lock it.

Comment: I don't see why you don't at least use `$count = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-".$post_slug."-2.txt")`   And then when you write, `file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-".$post_slug."-2.txt", $count, LOCK_EX)`  That way you open the file for the smallest amount of time and lock it on writes... but what do I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would at least change your code to this

```
foreach ($loveteam_children as $loveteam_child) {
    $post_slug = $loveteam_child->slug;
    echo "<script>console.log('".$post_slug."');</script>";
    if($loveteam_child->slug == "loveteam-mayward"){
        $filename = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-{$post_slug}.txt";
    }else{
        $filename = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/wp-content/themes/inside-showbiz-Vfeb13.ph-updated/countlog-{$post_slug}-2.txt";
    }

    $count = file_get_contents($filename);      
    file_get_contents($filename, ++$count, LOCK_EX);
}
```

You could also try `flock` on the file to get a lock before modifying it.  That way if another process comes along it has to wait on the first one.  But `file_put_contents` works great for things like logging where you may have many processes competing for the same file.

Database should be ok, but even that may not be fast enough. It shouldn't mess up your data though.

Anyway hope it helps.  This is kind of an odd question, concurrency can be a real pain if you have a high chance of process collisions and race conditions etc etc.

However as I mentioned (in the comments) using the filesystem is probably not going to provide the consistency you need.  Probably the best for this may be some kind of in memory storage such as Redis.  But that is hard to say without full knowing what you use it for.  For example if it should persist on server reboot.

Hope it helps, good luck.